# React redux Thunk - Making two ajax call one after the other with the result from the first ajax call using fetch API

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, fetch, redux-thunk

I am trying to make two ajax call one after the other , i.e with the result of the first call data , i am making the second call. I am trying to use thunk , but it is not happening , i am getting errors.

actions.js

```
const fetchedStateNameSucess = (json) => {
    return {
      type: 'FETCH_STATE_NAME_SUCCESS',
      json
    }
}

const fetchProvidersDetailsSuccess = (providersData) => {
    return {
      type: 'FETCH_PROVIDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS',
      providersData
    }
}


export const fetchProvidersDetails = (providerId) => {
 return (dispatch) => {
  const providerUrl = `http://someUrl`;
  const stateClientCountUrl = `http://someUrl/${state}`;
  fetch(providerUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => dispatch(fetchProvidersDetailsSuccess(json)))
  .then((stateValue = json[0].stateVal)
  fetch(stateClientCountUrl)
    dispatch(fetchedStateNameSucess(response)));
  };
}
```

In the above call , fetch(providerUrl) , i am getting response where i am getting the stateval , how to use that in making the second call to fetch(stateClientCountUrl) which takes stateval as a parameter.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error here?

Comment: I assume that you have got some typos in your code. Try to review and edit your question. You are dispatching several times the same action creator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Miguel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934001/miguel-calder%C3%B3n) said you can do your second query in `.then()` clause as well as you can use `async/await` syntax, something like this:

```
export const fetchProvidersDetails = providerId => {

 return async dispatch => {
  const providerUrl = `http://someUrl`;

  try {
       const response = await fetch(providerUrl);
       const json = await response.json();
       dispatch(fetchProvidersDetailsSuccess(json))

       const stateClientCountUrl = `http://someUrl/${json[0].stateVal}`;
       const response2 = await fetch(stateClientCountUrl);
       const json2 = await response2.json();
       dispatch(fetchedStateNameSucess(json2));
  } catch (error) {
       console.log('Error', error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use values from the first call response for the second fetch call, you need to do the second fetch after the first one has succeeded, more or less like this:

```
export const fetchProvidersDetails = (providerId) => {
 return (dispatch) => {
  const providerUrl = `http://someUrl`;
  const stateClientCountUrl = `http://someUrl/${state}`;
  fetch(providerUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    dispatch(fetchProvidersDetailsSuccess(json));
    const stateValue = json[0].stateVal;
      fetch(stateClientCountUrl)
      .then(response => dispatch(fetchProvidersDetailsSuccess(response)));
    })
}
```

Don't forget to add error handling there, both for HTTP status codes and for JavaScript errors (by adding corresponding `catch` clauses).